# image is not so clear after using this as background image

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

The original image is in a folder and being accessed by `background-image` CSS property to be used in a `div` as background image. But it does not look same as the original image. I have tried CSS3 `cover`, `image-rendering` etc to fix this but still no change in output. I also tried CSS3 filters but nothing changed.

**Original Image**

[image: original image]

**Image as div background**

[image: image in div background]

The code I tried:

```
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
background-image: url(img/15294860.jpeg)
```

Comment: It looks like you're scaling the image (as it's a 200x200 image, yet you specify 48x48), hence it gets resampled, and that's never a good thing. Use it at it's native size.

Comment: yes ! , the original image size is 200x200 and fixing in DIV size 48px , 48px any alternate if i am looking resolve the same thing instead of using image native size

Comment: Resize the image to 48x48 in an external program with a good resampling algorithm (Photoshop, GIMP etc) and then use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check below snippet i think it's looking proper. just add background-repeat: no-repeat; to remove repeat image.

```css
.image {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa1XR.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.background {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/lego/images/1/16/Harrypottery5-7-200x200.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111021110949")no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```